# Определить положение scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть во фрейме скролл бар, как я могу отследить его положение относительно оси Y. Мне нужно что бы когда его положение будет снизу(сделать скролл в самое нижнее состояние), то продолжать действие, в моем случае продолжать цикл загрузки данных.

```
mail_scroll_bar = Scrollbar(list_message_frame)
mail_scroll_bar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

mail_tree = ttk.Treeview(list_message_frame, yscrollcommand=mail_scroll_bar.set, 
    selectmode="extended")

mail_scroll_bar.config(command=mail_tree.yview)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При перемещении полосы прокрутки проверяете
`if mail_scroll_bar.get()[1] == 1`, значит он в нижнем положении.